# robots.txt: How to disallow all subdirectories but allow parent folder

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I'd like to disallow all subdirectories in my folder `/search` but allow indexing the search folder itself (I have content on `/search`).

Testing this does not work:

```
User-Agent: *
Allow: /search/
Disallow: /search/*
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code appears correct. Try with a slight adjustment to `Allow`:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /search/*
Allow: /search/$
```